# How to create a bulleted list in ReportLab

Tags: python, pdf, reportlab

How can I create a bulleted list in ReportLab? The documentation is frustratingly vague. I am trying:

```
text = ur '''
<para bulletText="&bull;">
item 1
</para>
<para bulletText="&bull;">
item 2
</para>
'''
Story.append(Paragraph(text,TEXT_STYLE))
```

But I keep getting errors like `list index out of range`. It seems that I can't put more than one `<para></para>` in a single call to `Paragraph()`? I also tried setting `TEXT_STYLE.bulletText="&bull;"` but that doesn't work either...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The bulletText argument is actually a constructor to the `Paragraph` object, not the `<para>` tag :-) Try this:

```
story.append(Paragraph(text, TEXT_STYLE, bulletText='-'))
```

Have a look at the examples on page 68 (page 74 now, in 2012) of the [ReportLab Documentation](http://www.reportlab.com/docs/reportlab-userguide.pdf), though. The convention in ReportLab seems to be to use the `<bullet>` tag, and the docs do warn that you can have only one per `Paragraph` instance. We render our bullets in ReportLab like so:

```
story.append(Paragraph('<bullet>The rain in spain</bullet>', TEXT_STYLE))
```

Comment: Good point... I was referring to the same documentation the OP mentioned. Amended to provide a link (and update the page number... is has been 3 years...).

Answer (score 10):

The very recent versions of ReportLab have ListFlowable and ListItem objects (check Chapter 9 of the current user guide).

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

```
Story.append(Paragraph('<bullet>&bull;</bullet>Some Text', styles["Bullet"]))
```